# highcharts javascript variables

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts in order to try to build a scatter graph with quarterly intervals.

Here is my code:

```
       laboreff = '';
          if    ( $.isArray(dataItem.content) ) {
            for (var i = 0, max = dataItem.content.length; i < max; i += 1) {
              laboreff += '{"x:Date.UTC('+'"'+dataItem.content[i].FiscalYear + '" ' + ', ' + '"' + dataItem.content[i].FiscalQuarter + '"'+'),"y":' + '"'+ dataItem.content[i].AverageLaborEfficiencyRatiobySICCode + '"'+'},';
            }
          }

          var laboreff = laboreff;
          var jannes = '[Date.UTC(2007,0,1),72634],[Date.UTC(2007,3,1),72634],[Date.UTC(2007,6,1),72634],[Date.UTC(2007,9,1),72634]';
//var jannes = JSON.parse("[" + jannes + "]")
//  var laboreff = $.parseJSON(laboreff);
        //console.log(laboreff); 
          Highcharts.setOptions({
            colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4']
          }
                               );
          var chartMain;
          chartMain = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
              type: 'line',
              renderTo: 'container2',
              alignTicks: true,
              borderWidth: 0,
              resetZoomButton: {
                position: {
                  align: 'right',
                  verticalAlign: 'top'
                }
              }
              ,
              shadow: true,
              spacingTop: 10,
              spacingRight: 20,
              spacingBottom: 50,
              spacingLeft: 20,
              zoomType: 'x'
            }
            ,
            credits: {
              enabled: false
            }
            ,
            legend: {
              align: 'center',
              enabled: true,
              itemStyle: {
                fontSize: '9px',
                width: '175px'
              }
              ,
              layout: 'horizontal',
              verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
            ,
            plotOptions: {
              series: {
                shadow: true
              }
              ,
              spline: {
                marker: {
                  enabled: false
                }
              }
            }
            ,
            subtitle: {
              align: 'center',
              text: 'Average Labor Efficiency Ratio by SIC code',
              style: {
                fontSize: '9px',
                width: '100%'
              }
              ,
              verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
            ,
            title: {
              text: ''
            }
            ,
            tooltip: {
              formatter: function () {
                var s = '<b>';
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Jan') {
                  s = s + "Q1"
                };
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Apr') {
                  s = s + "Q2"
                };
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Jul') {
                  s = s + "Q3"
                };
                if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Oct') {
                  s = s + "Q4"
                };
                s = s + " " + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.x) + '</b>';
                $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
                  s += '<br/>' + point.series.name + ': ';
                  if (point.series.name == 'Unemployment Rate (%)') {
                    s += Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 2, '.');
                  }
                  else {
                    s += Highcharts.numberFormat(point.y, 0, ',');
                  }
                }
                      );
                return s;
              }
              ,
              shared: true
            }
            ,
            xAxis: {
              ordinal:false,
              alternateGridColor: '#FAFAFA',
              labels: {
                style: {
                  fontSize: '9px',
                  width: '175px'
                }
                ,
                formatter: function () {
                  var s = "";
                  if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Jan') {
                    s = s + "Q1"
                  };
                  if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Apr') {
                    s = s + "Q2"
                  };
                  if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Jul') {
                    s = s + "Q3"
                  };
                  if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value) == 'Oct') {
                    s = s + "Q4"
                  };
                  s = s + " " + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value);
                  return s;
                }
              }
              ,
              tickInterval: 3 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
              type: 'datetime'
            }
            ,
            yAxis: [{
              endOnTick: true,
              gridLineWidth: 1,
              gridLineColor: '#BCCBA0',
              labels: {
                style: {
                  color: '#89A54E',
                  fontSize: '9px',
                  width: '175px'
                }
              }
              ,
              opposite: false,
              title: {
                text: ''
              }
            }
                   ],
            exporting: {
              buttons: {
                exportButton: {
                  align: 'right',
                  verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                  y: -5
                }
                ,
                printButton: {
                  symbol: 'url(/vos_v14_predev/vosnet/Handlers/Content/Images/Image.ashx?DotImage/Icons/Print_24.png)',
                  align: 'right',
                  height: 20,
                  symbolSize: 22,
                  symbolX: 12,
                  symbolY: 7.5,
                  verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                  width: 24,
                  y: -5
                }
              }
              ,
              width: 565
            }
            ,
            navigation: {
              buttonOptions: {
                enabled: false
              }
            }
            ,

            series: [{
             data: [ [Date.UTC(2007,0,1),72634],[Date.UTC(2007,3,1),72634],[Date.UTC(2007,6,1),72634],[Date.UTC(2007,9,1),72634] ],
   // data: [ laboreff or jannes variable], THIS DOES NOT WORK.
              name: 'Fisheries',
              type: 'scatter',
              yAxis: 0
            }
                    ]
          }
                                          );
                 alert(laboreff);
                console.log(jannes);
        }
      }
    }
                     );
  }
                     );
</script>
```

the variable laboreff gets the right contents and when i paste the console's value's into the series data it loads, i have tried Json.parse but because it's not valid json that doesnt work. Any idea why the graph doesnt load with the variable?

if I copy and paste the values from  both the variables jannes and laboreff from the console into data, it works.

Comment: Could you give us a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I would, but the json string that comes in is dynamically generated in the application..

Comment: Infowys.com/scott here it is, if you use the network insecptor and look at json.php that gets loaded, the json data is in there.

Comment: The functions in the JSON / string are not evaluated, so you cannot use them inside. Use the native timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

```
var laboreff = [];

if ($.isArray(dataItem.content)) {
    for (var i = 0, max = dataItem.content.length; i < max; i += 1) {
        laboreff.push({
            x: new Date(dataItem.content[i].FiscalYear).getTime(),
            y: dataItem.content[i].FiscalQuarter
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in HighCharts, you need to set a timestamp in order to define the x value  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<area>.data.x

Comment: Hi, I did that, All I get is [object] [object] You can view it here: infowys.com/scott

Comment: var laboreff = [];

if ($.isArray(dataItem.content)) {
    for (var i = 0, max = dataItem.content.length; i < max; i += 1) {
        laboreff.push({
            x: new Date(dataItem.content[i].FiscalYear).getTime(),
            y: dataItem.content[i].FiscalQuarter
        });
    }
}

Comment: series: [{
                 data: [ laboreff ],
                  name: 'Fisheries',
                  type: 'scatter',
                  yAxis: 0
                }

Comment: Log your data with console.log() instead of alert()

Comment: Hi, I did that and updated it, you can see the console.log

Comment: Your y value is a string you need to cast to Number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116497/discussion-between-johan-fourie-and-alexandre).